# SQL Query Start and End Date

Tags: sql, oracle10g

This is slightly different than this: [SQL Query Creating Start and End Dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5409018/sql-query-creating-start-and-end-dates)

And I do not know how to phrase this question as I suck in English.

Table

```
Name | Date
Foo | 1-Sep
Foo | 2-Sep
Foo | 3-Sep
Foo | 5-Sep
Foo | 6-Sep
Foo | 7-Sep

Foo | 1-Dec
Foo | 2-Dec

Foo | 4-Dec
Foo | 5-Dec
Foo | 6-Dec
Foo | 7-Dec
Foo | 8-Dec

Foo | 1-Feb

Foo | 14-Feb
Foo | 15-Feb
Foo | 16-Feb
Foo | 17-Feb
Foo | 18-Feb
Foo | 19-Feb
Foo | 20-Feb

Foo | 22-Feb
```

I need to create a query with the below result

Query Result

```
Name | Start Date  |  End Date
Foo  |  1-Sep      | 3-Sep
Foo  |  5-Sep      | 7-Sep
Foo  |  4-Dec      | 8-Dec
Foo  |  1-Feb      | 1-Feb
Foo  |  1-Dec      | 2-Dec
Foo  |  14-Feb     | 20-Feb
Foo  |  22-Feb     | 22-Feb
```

Update:

- **Start Date:** First day of a series of consecutive days
- **End Date:** Last day of a series of consecutive days
- *If a date is not included in a series of consecutive days, like Feb 22 above, it is the start and end date.*

Comment: Explain us why this output is correct, then we can help you with query

Comment: You should explain how you arrive at those end dates, especially 8-sep.

Comment: I just tried to explain. Hope it helps.

Comment: oops, sept 8 was wrong, It should be sep 7

Comment: @Anon, which version of SQL (Oracle, SQLServer, MySQL, PostgreSQL, etc) are you using? Date manipulation differs significantly between SQL flavours.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if its the best way. You can first filter all dates that have previous and next day, then you can use solution explained in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5409018/sql-query-creating-start-and-end-dates)

Query that filters unimportant dates:

```
select t1.Name, t.Date from Table t1
left outer join Table t2 on dateadd(d,-1,t1.Date) = t2.Date 
left outer join Table t3 on dateadd(d,1,t1.Date) = t3.Date
where t2.Date is null or t3.Date is null
```